# How can i get the logs of git using github API

Tags: command, github-api, github-api-v3

I referred to many documents to get the logs of GitHub using GitHub API. But I couldn't find the way. I want to get the logs of GitHub events(commit, changes, etc..) and send them to cloudwatch. How can I achieve this? Or any other way to get the log without using authentication?
For example, I need a command like this so that I can get the logs without touching GitHub

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: token <PAT token>." \
    https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

or any program to get the logs is welcome
or Any rest API to get the GitHub logs
I am not familiar with GitHub. can anyone give me a solution or idea?
below I mentioned the links that I have followed. Anyone can refer and if possible modify any command or API call to get the logs it would be great.

https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/github-rest-api-tutorial/

https://dev.to/gr2m/github-api-authentication-personal-access-tokens-53kd

https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=f441bab7-8fc8-45ae-b12b-4c41efbbe2d1

Comment: `git log` - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Comment: To execute these commands we need to configure git in my server I don't want to configure but I need to access the logs by API or program

Comment: Git is a program with an API.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. I am not familiar with git. I need to know the answer. at any program or API, I need to get the logs. I can't follow the git config in the server.